# Listing filters in geth. Do they timeout and expire?

Tags: go-ethereum, console, filters

Suppose I make a JSON-RPC call to create a new filter as follows (from the [documention page](https://github.com/ethereumproject/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_newfilter)):

```
// Request
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_newFilter","params":[{"topics":["0x12341234"]}],"id":73}'

// Result
{
  "id":1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": "0x1" // This is the filter ID- 0x1
}
```

Now I have registered a filter at the geth client and now I can make further calls to the filter.

Can I go to the geth console and list all the registered filters (in case I forget them or just for other reasons)? Do they ever expire/timeout except of course after a restart which clears all the filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I go to the geth console and list all the registered filters (in case I forget them or just for other reasons)?

AFAIK there is no way to list the installed filters, at least with the exposed APIs.

> Do they ever expire/timeout except of course after a restart which clears all the filters.

From [JSON RPC documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC): "Filters timeout when they aren't requested with eth_getFilterChanges for a period of time." In Geth implementation, the time period is 5 minutes from the last poll of eth_getFilterChanges after which the filter expires.